# I cant hide divs which has spesific class with Jquery

Tags: jquery

> **edit**:

I changed my code to below code but this code doesnt make anything, no changing, no displaying:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
if( $(".ea-standard form div").hasClass("disabled") ){
        alert($(".ea-standard form div").hasClass("disabled"));
    $('.disabled').hide();
    } } );
jQuery(function ($) {
$(".ea-standard form div.disabled").alert($(".ea-standard form div").hasClass("disabled"));
    } );
jQuery(function ($) {
$(".ea-standard form div.disabled").hide();
    } );
```

why?

---

I have a form and when you select an option on a selectable list, other selectable lists on the form get ".disabled" form.But the disabled class doesnt disable them.

to disabled other selectable lists, I want to hide all things which has ".disable" class.

to make this, I wrote this code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".ea-standard form div").hasClass(("disabled") => {
        alert($(".ea-standard form div").hasClass("disabled"));
    $('.disabled').hide();
    });
});
```

I want to check all form div and if any div get ".disabled" class in anytime, hide it suddenly.

but my js code editor says:

Expected an identifier and instead saw "disabled" . for this line:

```
$(".ea-standard form div").hasClass(("disabled") => {
how to solve?
```

Comment: actually, why don't you just hide that class by css?

Comment: _“how to solve?”_ - that particular error - probably by removing the _extra_ `(` you put in there.

Answer (score 0):

**JS:**

```
jQuery(function($) {
 $('div.ea-standard.disabled').hide();
});
```

**CSS:**
Use simple `CSS` code to achieve it, use CSS with class `.disabled` to hide them like

```
div.ea-standard.disabled{
 display:none;
}
```

or if you want to remove only mouse events then use

```
div.ea-standard.disabled{
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

Which disable all mouse events over elements that have `.disabled` class is added

Comment: your code doesnt work also it is same with mine.the form is related a wordpress plugin and it get ".disabled" class from the plugin's js file.The js file is too large and complex so I cant set control over it.can you look at my last question which give more information about this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65560911/i-cant-affect-a-class-which-is-under-effect-from-another-js-jquery

Comment: Need to use CSS then, or load your JS file at the end using WP actions and hooks. So your code is running at last after plugin JS code.

Comment: no, it is not css or wp issue.I solved it.unfortunately my solution way doesnt work so I found a new way: I hide all divs which has step except first div with jquery

Comment: after changing the first dropdown value, other steps are still hidden https://prnt.sc/wg1lvj

Answer (score 0):

unfortunaly, my method doesnt work. but I found a new solution:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".ea-standard form div.step").not(':eq(0)').hide();
} );
```

this hide all divs which has step class except first div